# How to remove repeating values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Time       x     y
00:10:00   5.4   4.2
00:20:00   6.2   5.2
00:30:00   4.1   5.2
00:40:00   5.8   5.2
00:50:00   5.1   3.8
```

I need to find a way to remove the consecutive repeating values (5.2) in y. I can't use pd.drop_duplicates() as that would remove genuine 5.2 values from the data. I'd rather not iterate through each row as it is a very large dataframe and feels like poor pandas practice. I'm hoping there's a nice method I'm missing but haven't found one on my search so far.

Many Thanks

Comment: what should be there instead? what about their corresponding `x`s?

Comment: I can't understand whether you want to drop lines 3-4 or something else. Nonetheless, "I can't use pd.drop_duplicates() as that would remove genuine 5.2 values from the data" - you can use `keep` argument in that method to keep the first/last record.

Comment: ^^ incorrect if there are other 5.2 spread out which aren't grouped together then you would remove those values, seems like he just wants to remove it where the values repeat and follow one another

Comment: Did not expect to get responses this quickly, thanks very much.

Comment: So yeah the reason I don't want to use drop_duplicates is as aws_apprentice says, because my df is big I have a lot of genuine values between 0 and 25 which I don't want to discard. Also yes it is the consecutive repeating values I want to remove. As to Adam.Er8's question: I want to remove those rows not replace the values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to drop *consecutive duplicates*, we can use [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) with [`.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and [`.ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) here.

**note**: I extended your dataframe with 1 row to show the method works:

```
# Extended example dataframe
       Time    x    y
0  00:10:00  5.4  4.2
1  00:20:00  6.2  5.2
2  00:30:00  4.1  5.2
3  00:40:00  5.8  5.2
4  00:50:00  5.1  3.8
5  00:60:00  3.3  5.2
```

---

```
m = df['y'].shift().ne(df['y'])
df[m]

       Time    x    y
0  00:10:00  5.4  4.2
1  00:20:00  6.2  5.2
4  00:50:00  5.1  3.8
5  00:60:00  3.3  5.2
```

---

`ne` is the equivalent of `!=` and stands for *not equal*:

```
df['x'] != 5.4 
df['x'].ne(5.4)

0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
Name: x, dtype: bool
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
Name: x, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Erfan. Could you explain what the .ne is doing here? I'm not familiar with that method

Comment: Works beautifully by the way.

Comment: Sure, I edited my answer with explanation on the bottom. @BilboSwaggins

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for your help; appreciate the quick responses.